# Maven not loading the property file installed in repository

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have two maven projects, spring-persistence and spring-web.

spring-persistence is installed in my local repository which is then referenced in spring-web application.

My spring-persistence project has two maven profiles configuration, `dev` and `test`. **dev** profile is set as `activeByDefault` profile. Here's how I install spring-persistence using the `test` profile for test database connections.

```
mvn clean install -Ptest
```

After  spring-persistence has been installed, I used to check the generated jar file to see if the correct properties have been set and no issue found.

Here's the issue, whenever I run my spring-web project it's not reading the configured property inside the installed spring-persistence jar file, instead it loads the profile **dev** which is set as `activeByDefault`. I'm sure it only loads the active profile because when I interchanged the configuration, the `test` was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of resolving the issue, I finally found the resolution.

I just have to Disable Workspace Resolution in my spring-web project.

```
Right Click - Maven - Disable Workspace Resolution
```

This will use the jar file in local repository instead of the project referenced.